# ThreadPool Windows phone App 8.1

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, threadpool

I'm developing Windows phone app. I stay at Write Database concurrent. But i know can't write database concurrent. I should use ThreadPool to push some Thread into queue. And process sequence. To avoid write DB concurrent. But I can't clearly some example in MSDN. Anyone know. Now I just have 2 method Async. And inside it have instruction to write database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a method sequentially (from any thread) you could use `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Semaphore to block access method. Only one thread at a time can execute this part of code.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async Task AsyncMethod()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

            // TODO critical code

            _semaphore.Release();
        });
    }
```